# Show legacy menu in newer android devices

Tags: android

We know that actionbar controller is introduced in newer android devices. When the theme which actionbar attribute used is set in a activity,the old method Activity.onCreateOptionMenus(Menu menu) is called whether or not user presses the device menu button(which newer android devices even don't have but a simulative menu button is provided) for creating actionbar.
And the problem is, I wish use the old legacy menu namely a simulative menu in newer devices,but that menu doesn't appear,onCreateOptionMenus is also not called, unless I point level 13 or lower as the target version.

Does any other way available??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You shouldn't be using the old menu style, it's obsolete and makes your app look incredibly out of date on newer devices. If you truly wish to use it, then you'll have to target a lower API.

Answer (score 0):

I leave the question of whether or not you *should* do this to you, but it is possible to do it.  Please see [Manually Adding the Legacy Overflow Button when targetSdkVersion >= 14](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2012/08/manually-adding-legacy-overflow-button.html)